# Donut Chart Google Vue

Tags: google-chart-api

Tengo un problema con la librería de [google charts de vue](https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts) al realizar un ejemplo de dicha libreria me da un error el cual no he podido solventar al parecer falta algun parametro o algo que haga que me funciones el donut chart.

Este seria mi **ejemplo**.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <GChart type="DonutChart" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { GChart } from "vue-google-charts";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    GChart,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Array will be automatically processed with visualization.arrayToDataTable function
      chartData: [
        ["Task", "Hours per Day"],
        ["Work", 11],
        ["Eat", 2],
        ["Commute", 2],
        ["Watch TV", 2],
        ["Sleep", 7],
      ],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          title: "Company Performance",
          subtitle: "Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017",
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

El detalle es que con dunut chart no funciona y me da el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization[type] is not a constructor
    at createChart (app.js?1126288863:197256)
    at VueComponent.createChartObject (app.js?1126288863:197256)
    at app.js?1126288863:197256
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple es cambiar "DonutChart" por "PieChart":

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <GChart type="PieChart" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Ver la documentación oficial aquí: [Making a Donut Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-donut-chart)